# How to open fragment in navigation drawer which have dynamic menu list from dynamic array

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-menu

I have created navigation drawer which have dynamic menu options which comes from my api now I want to open fragment based on option which I select from navigation drawer,I want to open fragment of sub options of main options from navigation item.

For example in my navigation drawer I have dynamic array which have four value 1)reports 2)Analysis 3)Contact us 4)About us

In reports I have one value portfolio report when i click on it i want to open that fragment, how can i achieve this? my array is dynamic and main array has report id and sub options array has parent id how I compare it with menu options id.

```
This is my code.

    MainActivity.java

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame
                            , new DashboardFragment())
                    .commit();

            initView();
            onClick();


            listData = new ArrayList<>();
            parentIdList = new ArrayList<>();
            reportIdList = new ArrayList<>();
            listSubData = new ArrayList<>();
            reportSubList = new ArrayList<>();

            toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightBlue));
            toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            //drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);

            drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);

    //        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    //        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0059b3")));


            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            loginid = sp.getInt("loginId", 0);
            userrole = sp.getInt("userrole", 0);
            clientid = sp.getInt("clientid", 0);
            username = sp.getString("username", "");


            Log.e(" prefs loginId", String.valueOf(loginid));
            Log.e("prefs userrole", String.valueOf(userrole));
            Log.e(" prefs clientid", String.valueOf(clientid));

            if (userrole == 99) {
                tvUserRole.setText("CLIENT");
                tvUserName.setText(username);
            } else {
                tvUserRole.setText("PARTNER");
                tvUserName.setText(username);
            }


            NavigationOptionsData(String.valueOf(userrole), String.valueOf(loginid), "A");

            for(int i=0;i<reportIdList.size();i++)
            {
                if(MenuItemId == reportIdList.get(i))
                {

                    Log.e("Menuitemid=", String.valueOf(MenuItemId));

    //                fragToCall = listData.get(i);
    //                ReportFragment fragment = new ReportFragment();
    //                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    //                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, fragToCall);
    //                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.test_fragment, fragment, "testtag");
    //
    //                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragToCall);
    //                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("Not equal", "");
                }
            }

        }

        private void initView() {

            navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            rvNavOptions = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rv_nav_data);
            rvNavSubOptions = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rv_nav_sub_data);

            header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
            tvUserName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_name_drawer);
            tvUserRole = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_role_drawer);
            tvOptionsId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_option_id);


        }




        private void NavigationOptionsData(String roleid, String loginId, String device) {

            final APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
            final NavigationDrawerModel navigationDrawerModel = new NavigationDrawerModel(roleid, loginId, device);
            Call<NavigationDrawerModel> call1 = apiInterface.createNavigationOption(navigationDrawerModel);
            call1.enqueue(new Callback<NavigationDrawerModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<NavigationDrawerModel> call, Response<NavigationDrawerModel> response) {
                    user1 = response.body();

                    Log.e("Navigation data===", user1.getT0().get(0).getReportText());
                    Log.e("Length of t0====", String.valueOf(user1.getT0().size()));
                    Log.e("Length of t1====", String.valueOf(user1.getT1().size()));

                    for (int i = 0; i < user1.getT0().size(); i++) {


                        String reportText = user1.getT0().get(i).getReportText();
                        Integer reportId = user1.getT0().get(i).getReportId();
                        reportIdList.add(reportId);
                        listData.add(reportText);

                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < user1.getT1().size(); i++) {

                        Integer reportParentId = user1.getT1().get(i).getParentId();
                        String reportSubName = user1.getT1().get(i).getReportText();
                        parentIdList.add(reportParentId);
                        listSubData.add(reportSubName);
                    }

                    Log.e("Size of parentid list==", String.valueOf(parentIdList.size()));
                    Log.e("Size of reportid list==", String.valueOf(reportIdList.size()));


                    navigationDrawerMenu = new NavigationDrawerMenu(listData, parentIdList, getApplicationContext());
                    rvNavOptions.setAdapter(navigationDrawerMenu);


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<NavigationDrawerModel> call, Throwable t) {

                    Log.e("Error is==", t.getMessage());
                }


            });
        }


        private void onClick() {

            rvNavOptions.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                    navigationDrawerMenu.onClick(view);
                    MenuItemId = (int) id;
                    Log.e("id of item click", String.valueOf(id));


                }
            });

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            Log.e("Menu item id is=", String.valueOf(id));
            return true;
        }
```

I compared menuitemid with reportidlist item is it correct?

Comment: You can use custom navigation drawer with dynamic list (Recycler View, Expandable listview etc.) and set that list menu items according to your api and then use on click method to change fragments.

Comment: I used listview